# Entity Framework does not generate dbset for a table. What is the reason?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework 6, every time I change the database, I go to the `.edmx` file and update the model from database. A dbset will be generated under the entity class for me to call LINQ. But for an unknown reason, a table I added does not have a corresponding `DbSet`. As a result I cannot do anything.

What is the reason for this problem?

The table has a primary key on an identity column.

In a normal case, I will do

```
public void MakeSomething() {
   using (var db = new WWWEntities()) {
      Something s = new Something() {
         info1 = "",
         info2 = ""
      };
      db.Somethings.Add(s); 
      db.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

But now `db.Somethings` does not exist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43270267/34092

Comment: @mjwills, I have done all the steps in the post you mentioned. That's why I dont know what's the problem and what to do.

Comment: Please show us a screenshot of your edmx model, which includes your new table.

Comment: @mjwills, here you are. The table name is `StageEng` which located in upper right. I cannot show the whole things because it is very large (around 300 tables)
!(http://cnow.co/ttt.png).

Comment: Please update your question with the real code you are trying.

Comment: Is there an unsupported data type in the table? Maybe you better show its DDL.

Comment: @GertArnold, No. 3 columns are types `int`, `int` and `nvarchar(50)`

Answer (score 1):

fixed. Since the `Entities` is a partial class, I added the `DBSet` in another partial class so that I can access the table

```
public partial class WWWEntities2 : DbContext
    {
        public WWWEntities2(String connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<StageEng> StageEng { get; set; }
    }
```